# 'BooleanField' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Tags: html, django, django-models

I am getting the error 'BooleanField' object has no attribute 'attrs'
I am creating a form to create a new user and save the details in the database

searched for a while but no luck
Add user source code
    `enter code here`

```
class AddUser(forms.ModelForm):
password=forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput)
date_of_join=forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
superuser=forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.BooleanField)
class Meta:
    model=User_list
      fields=['first_name','last_name','email','password','date_of_join','superuser'  ]
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <span class="text-danger small">{{field.errors}} </span>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }}      </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{field}}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

`field.label_tag` shows error for boolean field

error is this

```
 id_ = widget.attrs.get('id') or self.auto_id
AttributeError: 'BooleanField' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

The view:

```
class createuser(View):
    form_class=AddUser
    template_name='Account/userlist_form.html'

    def get(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})

    def post(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})
```

and my form:

```
class AddUser(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput)
    date_of_join=forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    superuser=forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.BooleanField)

    class Meta:
        model=User_list
        fields=['first_name','last_name','email','password','date_of_join','superuser']
```

Comment: Looks like you probably used a model field instead of a form field in your form. Can you share the code of your form?

Comment: class createuser(View):
    form_class=AddUser
    template_name='Account/userlist_form.html'
    def get(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})
    def post(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})

Comment: please [edit] your question with the source code of the `AddUser` class.

Comment: can you please [edit] the question and share the code of the *form* (the `AddUser` class).

Comment: class AddUser(forms.ModelForm):

    password=forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput)

    date_of_join=forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    superuser=forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.BooleanField)
    class Meta:
        model=User_list
        fields=['first_name','last_name','email','password','date_of_join','superuser']

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you use a `BooleanField` as *widget* for a `BooleanField`. Indeed, you write:

```
class AddUser(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput)
    date_of_join = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    superuser = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.BooleanField)

    # ...
```

A `BooleanField` is *not* a *widget*, so you can not use it a widget. The default widget is the [**`CheckboxInput`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxinput). In case you use that widget, you do not need to specify it, otherwise you can specify another *widget*. Not a formfield, like:

```
class AddUser(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput)
    date_of_join = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    superuser = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput)

    # ...
```

That being said, your code shows a lot of anti-patterns. For example you render the template for a POST request, even if the form is successful. By doing that, a user might refresh the browser, and submit the form a second time. You should use the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) here.

You do *not* need to write this boilerplate logic in your view, you can use a `CreateView` instead:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class createuser(CreateView):
    form_class = AddUser
    template_name = 'Account/userlist_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('some_view')
```

Here the `CreateView` will take care of the form, you only will need to fill in the name of the view to which you will redirect in case the form is succesfull.

Django models are typically singular, and without a suffix that makes them a collection, so you better name your model `User` instead of <s>`User_list`</s>.

The name of a `Form` class typically ends with the `Form` suffix. It is also common *not* to specify a method, since you can "reuse" the form to update a model instance, so it is probably better to name your form `UserForm`, instead of <s>`AddUser`</s>.

Your `createuser` class-based view is a class, so that means it should follow the [*PEP-8 style guide* [PEP-8]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Furthermore it might be better to use the `View` suffix here, so you better use the name `CreateUserView` instead of `createuser`.

You here probably store a password in the `User` model, if you only need to update and verify passwords, you better [hash these passwords [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/). Since otherwise if the database is hacked, the passwords can easily be retrieved.